# Remove text between angle tag as <uid></uid>

Tags: c#

```
   var text1 = "This <uid>123456</uid> works fine!";
   text1 = Regex.Replace(text1, @"\<uid>.*\</uid>", "");
   Console.WriteLine(text1);
   this give output as -This works fine!";
   i want to output as -This <uid></uid> works fine!;
```

The Regex expression removes all text between the FIRST opening angle  tag
and LAST closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it with desired `<uid></uid>` instead of replacing with empty string.

Like his:

```
var text1 = "This <uid>123456</uid> works fine!";
text1 = Regex.Replace(text1, @"\<uid\>.*\</uid\>", "<uid></uid>");
Console.WriteLine(text1);
```